# Prove $d$ is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> 1. $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$
> 2. $d(y,x)\leq d(z,y)+d(z,x)$

I have started with symmetry:

Let $x=z$ so:
$$d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)+d(x,x)$$

$$d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)$$

But I can find how to prove  $$d(y,x)\geq d(x,y)$$ to get an equality

Comment: Swap $x$ and $y$, they are arbitrary numbers.

Comment: @Siminore to take $x=y$?

Comment: No, repeat what you have done with $x$ in place of $y$ and $y$ in place of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've proved that for all $(x,y)\in X\times X$, $d(y,x)\le d(x,y)$. For any pair $(x,y)\in X\times X$, apply this inequality to the pair $(y,x)\in X\times X$. This yields the second inequality $d(x,y)\le d(y,x)$.

(2)+symmetry implies transitivity, and (1) + (2) applied to the triple $(x,x,z)$ becomes $$\forall (x,z)\in X\times X,\ 0\le 2d(z,x)$$

Which is non-negativity.

Answer (score 1):

Inequality $(2) $ gives

$$d(y,x)\leq d(z,x)+d(z,y) $$
and
$$d(x,y)\leq d(z,x)+d(z,y) $$

so with $z=x $ in the first, we get

$$d(y,x)\leq d(x,y) $$

and  $z=y $ in the second gives
$$d(x,y)\leq d(y,x) $$

thus $d (x,y)=d (y,x) $.

may be you will need $d (x,y)\geq 0$.

Comment: @gbox you plug $z=y $ the other.

Comment: Yes, Got it just the $d(z,x)$

Answer (score 0):

$d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)$ translated in plain English means "swapping the elements I get a distance less or equal than the previous one". If you iterate this twice you get the original distance:
$$d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)\leq d(y,x)$$
which implies the equal sign.